# How can I iteratively store several vectors from a list into appropriate columns in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, iteration

I generated 30 imputed dataframes, which are stored in a list `list.of.imputed.dfs`, which is of classes `"mild" "list"`. Some of the values in the dataframes need to be changed based on earlier values to create a survival outcome. For instance, if an observation takes on the value 1 for `var1`, all subsequent values (e.g., `var2`) are 1, otherwise the observations keep their original values. To do this, I used the following code:

```
a <- lapply(list.of.imputed.dfs), function(x1) {ifelse((x1$var1 == 1), 1, x1$var2}).
```

`a` is now a list of 30 vectors (one for each imputed dataframe) with the updated values for `var2`. Now, I want to store these values back into the appropriate column of each dataframe in `list.of.imputed.dfs`. To do this, I am currently using the following code and it works:

```
list.of.imputed.dfs$`1`$var2 <- a$`1`
list.of.imputed.dfs$`2`$var2 <- a$`2`
...
list.of.imputed.dfs$`30`$var2 <- a$`30`
```

where, for example, the `1` on the left is the imputed dataframe and the `1` on the right is the vector from the newly created list. The `...` means that there are 28 more lines for each imputed dataframe and each vector from the newly created list `a`.

I actually have to change the outcome to be a survival outcome at a total of three locations (`var2, var3, and var4`), which means at least 90 lines of code to store these values back into the appropriate columns of the appropriate imputed dataframe. What I would like to know is how to iterate over the list I created (`a`) to iteratively store the values back into the imputed dataframes. Or do I even need to store the updated values in `a` before trying to store them back into the appropriate columns of the appropriate dataframes of `list.of.imputed.dfs`? Thanks for any help you can provide!

reproducible example based on Samuel Calderon's advice.

```
# Simulating data
set.seed(500)
N <- 100
data <- data.frame(id = 1:N,
                   tx = rbinom(100, 1, .75),
                   var1 = rbinom(100, 1, .20),
                   var2 = rbinom(100, 1, .30),
                   var3 = rbinom(100, 1, .40),
                   var4 = rbinom(100, 1, .50))
                   
                   
c_names <- c("tx", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")
prc_missing <- 0.20

# Simulating missingness in the data
data <- data %>%
  gather(var, value, -id) %>%
  mutate(r = runif(nrow(.)),
         value = ifelse(var %in% c_names & r <= prc_missing, NA, value)) %>% select(-r) %>% spread(var, value)

# Imputing data to account for assumed MAR
imputed.data <- mice(data, m = 30, maxit = 50, method = "pmm", seed = 500)
list.of.imputed.dfs <- complete(imputed.data, "all")

# Trying to apply new values over original values
modify_vars <- function(x) {
  x$var2 <- ifelse(x$var1 == 1, 1, x$var2)
  x$var3 <- ifelse(x$var2 == 1, 1, x$var3)
  x$var4 <- ifelse(x$var3 == 1, 1, x$var4)
  x
}
lapply(list.of.imputed.dfs, modify_vars)
```

Comment: How many rows per df? I ask this to know if it is possible to work with just one big df or if there are memory limits

Comment: Hi Samuel, I have 1,538 rows per df, but I need to keep them separate to then combine the estimates in an analysis with Rubin's rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to modify a dataframe individually, then apply to all the elements in the list.

```r
modify_vars <- function(x) {
    x$var2 <-  ifelse(x$var1 == 1, 1, x$var2)
    x$var3 <-  ifelse(x$var1 == 1, 1, x$var3)
    x$var4 <-  ifelse(x$var1 == 1, 1, x$var4)
    x
}

lapply(list_of_dfs, modify_vars)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Running your code gets me the same answer I got with how I was using lapply, which is a list of five vectors. The problem is storing the vectors into the appropriate imputed dataframes' appropriate columns.

Comment: My code modifies the variables inside de dfs and returns a list of dfs. Where do you get a list of vectors?

Comment: I created a reproducible example to go off of so we are on the same page.  See the question with updated code.

Comment: I see, you forgot to add the `x` before the clossing `}` when creating `modify_vars()`

Comment: For future readers of this question and answer, I updated the code in the question to reflect a corrected reproducible example.